# Are there any compilers/interpreters that optimize operations not in-place to in-place?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, vectorization, compiler-optimization, in-place

I observe errors like this pretty often when I grade papers (and definitely make them myself on occasion):

```
% any vectorized language, such as MATLAB/Octave/R that supports logical indexing
Y = rand(1,10); % random numbers drawn uniformly from the interval [0,1] in a 1x10 vector
Y(Y<=0.6) = 1;
Y(Y>0.6) = 0; % These two lines try to convert the distribution from uniform to Bernoulli
```

This code results in a vector of zeros, not the desired random binary vector whose distribution approximates a Bernoulli random variable.

The problem, from a programming perspective, is in the in-place modification; the coder skips a mental step. (There are other ways to solve this, based on the mathematics the code is supposed to accomplish, or by switching the conditionals, etc., but those are all application specific.) A unit test would lay the error bare, but I've been unable to convince any students to try them (it's not a programming class, specifically). Code that first allocates an output vector and fills it based on the input vector would prevent this from happening:

```
X = rand(1,10); % random numbers in a 1x10 vector
Y = zeros(size(X));
Y(X<=0.6) = 1;
Y(X>0.6) = 0;
```

However, this is guaranteed to take twice the space, although I would say it better fits the mental model of the mistaken coder here, and in general is easier to figure out than a really intricate algorithm that wastes no space at all (see the CLRS illustration of quicksort).

Are there any compilers/interpreters that optimize code like the second snippet to reduce the required space to that of an in-place operation?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil, does the extra storage really matter?

Comment: Not when it's 10 points, no, but if it were an input of 10 million points and production code for an embedded system, I'd want either careful habits or a compiler that could optimize this kind of space usage.

Comment: Sure. Imagine a Fortran compiler computing  A = A + B, where A and B are huge matrices.  The naive implementation of this is T = A + B;  A = T with a big waste of space for T.  But a compiler doing a lifetime analysis can realize the the "old A" is dead, and reuse the space for the new A.  This is pretty common in array-oriented Fortran compilers.

Comment: The problem is that for some problems, you need a *radically* different algorithm to cut down space cost. Generally, compiler optimizations don't fundamentally rewrite algorithms. In simple cases, things like Ira Baxter's example can be done (this can be further faciliated by language language design, e.g. linear typing). But in your example, `X` cannot be re-used for `Y` because their life times overlap, and to remove that the compiler would have to figure out how to merge the two statements `Y(X<=0.6) = 1; Y(X>1) = 0;` while making sure no slot of `X` that's been reused is accessed later on.

Comment: So would you say that the lifetime analysis mentioned by Ira is relatively common, and probably the best you can expect?

Comment: Most modern compilers have a pretty good idea of named variable lifetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are. There are a few different optimizations that are in the area you discuss:

- Many C++ compilers will do [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) to avoid creating a new temporary object only to immediately copy it over an existing one.
- The [allocation sinking](http://wiki.luajit.org/Allocation-Sinking-Optimization) that LuaJIT and some other compilers do may be similar to what you have in mind.
- [Scalar replacement of aggregates](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pq7pHwG1_OkC&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=scalar+replacement+of+aggregates&source=bl&ots=4Xb0Gvb8rM&sig=RQQfShw083BocohuAhU5cp3SLR4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8_ugUrLsCsfniAKin4HwAw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=scalar%20replacement%20of%20aggregates&f=false) is also in the same vein.